# Import app's packages without sending the actual code

Tags: android, import

I have written an android app, and now another app needs to use some of my data (both apps will be on the same device so access to the database is granted). How can the second app import my packages without having the actual code? Or what should I send in order for the second app to have access to my functions without actually seeing the implementation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

OR

[Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) using [aidl](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: If you want to share database or file data, create a content provider in your first app. And you can consume your custom content provider from the second app just like how we get "contacts" from Phone app.

Create AIDL service. you can get complete idea on how to create it and invoke it from the above linked android dev guide page. (it accepts only List, String, CharSequence or Map type of data)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. Put below code in your main activity from where you want to pass the data.

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.your_app_package_name.your_app_name.ActivtiyAlpha");
i.putExtra("KEY_DATA_EXTRA_FROM_ACTV_B", myString);
// add extras to any other data you want to send to b
```

and in other activity.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras;
if(b!=null){
    String myString = b.getString("KEY_DATA_EXTRA_FROM_ACTV_B");
    // and any other data that the other app sent
}
```

Comment: This won't help because I don't want to send data to the other app... I want the other app to have access to my functions without having the actual code. For example the other app will have "import com.my_package.my_class" and then he can create objects from my class.